# Python pyqgis how to load vector layer from a list

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

How can I load vector layer from a list? Such as

```
latitude = [...] 
longitude = [...]
some_data_belongs_to_the_coordinates = [...]

vector_layer = QgsVectorLayer(?)
```

Comment: Tricky question. You need the right provider according to the [Class: QgsVectorLayer](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayer.html). Maybe a workaround could be to write down the data in a .csv inside a temp folder and then load it.

Comment: Yes this is what i am doing right now but i just want to remove unneccesary csv implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find attached a small code fraqment (qgis 2.18) which adds points from 3 lists to a memory layer. May be that helps:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant

latitude = [10,20,30] 
longitude = [30,40,50]
some_data_belongs_to_the_coordinates = [100,200.1,300]

layer = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=epsg:4326', 'MyPoint' ,'memory')
fields = QgsFields()
fields.append(QgsField('value', QVariant.Double))
pr = layer.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes(fields)
layer.updateFields()

for i in range(0, len(latitude)):
    pt = QgsFeature()
    point1 = QgsPoint(longitude[i],latitude[i])
    pt.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point1))
    pt.setAttributes([some_data_belongs_to_the_coordinates[i]])
    pr.addFeatures([pt])
    layer.updateExtents()

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

Comment: can someone explain that : What are the dataproviders for vector layers and how to use them?. i have searched for the cookbook but there was too few data provider example about this.